# Recyclerview-selection select sometimes 2 items when I long click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, selection, android-viewholder, multipleselection

I created a recyclerview with a StaggeredGridLayoutManager as LayoutManager.

I wanted to implement a multiple selection thanks to the recyclerview-selection library but when I make a long click on a certain item, it sometimes selects 2. (I am using a DB to retrieve the data)

---

This is my main code:

```
GridRecyclerView notesRecyclerView = binding.noteRecyclerView;
notesRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

adapter = new NoteAdapterTest();
notesRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

SelectionTracker<Long> tracker = new SelectionTracker.Builder<>("mySelection", notesRecyclerView,
                new StableIdKeyProvider(notesRecyclerView),
                new NoteDetailsLookup(notesRecyclerView),
                StorageStrategy.createLongStorage())
                .withSelectionPredicate(SelectionPredicates.createSelectAnything()).build();

adapter.setSelectionTracker(tracker);
```

My Adapter:

```
    private SelectionTracker<Long> selectionTracker;
    private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Note> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Note>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Note oldItem, @NonNull Note newItem) {
            return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Note oldItem, @NonNull Note newItem) {
            return oldItem.getTitle().equals(newItem.getTitle()) && oldItem.getContent().equals(newItem.getContent());
        }
    };

    public NoteAdapterTest() {
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        AdapterNoteBinding binding = AdapterNoteBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
        return new NoteHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Note note = getItem(position);
        ((NoteHolder) holder).bind(note, selectionTracker.isSelected((long) position));
    }


    public static class NoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        private final AdapterNoteBinding binding;

        public NoteHolder(@NonNull AdapterNoteBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        public final void bind(Note note, boolean isActive) {
            Context context = binding.getRoot().getContext();
            itemView.setActivated(isActive);

            if (isActive) {
                binding.noteAdapterLayout.getBackground().setTint(context.getColor(R.color.blue));

                
            } else {
                binding.noteTitle.setText(note.getTitle());
                
            }
        }


        public ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long> getItemDetails() {
            return new ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>() {

                @Override
                public int getPosition() {
                    return getAdapterPosition();
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Long getSelectionKey() {
                    return getItemId();
                }
            };
        }
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void setSelectionTracker(SelectionTracker<Long> selectionTracker) {
        this.selectionTracker = selectionTracker;
    }

    }
```

My lookup:

```
public class NoteDetailsLookup extends ItemDetailsLookup<Long> {

    private final RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public NoteDetailsLookup(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    }


     @Nullable
     @Override
     public ItemDetails<Long> getItemDetails(@NonNull MotionEvent e) {
         View view = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
         if (view != null) {
             RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view);
             if (viewHolder instanceof NoteAdapterTest.NoteHolder) {
                 return ((NoteAdapterTest.NoteHolder) viewHolder).getItemDetails();
             }
         }
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Comment: For multiselection I would recommend using `Contextual Action Mode` with `MaterialCardView`. Check out my demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btOT7wNaajY and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFjQrh2IyDg。

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't fix my issue. I don't want to show a contextual action mode in my case.

Comment: What actions you provide to user when items are selected? And how do you provide these actions? `Button`s? `Dialog`?

Comment: I use a BottomAppBar with a different menu when the user selects one or more items

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that 2 items are selected? What the selection tracker returns? 
Try to set background tint in your view holder always:

```
if (isActive) {
    binding.noteAdapterLayout.getBackground().setTint(context.getColor(R.color.blue));
} else {
    binding.noteAdapterLayout.getBackground().setTint(context.getColor(R.color.white)); // your default color
}
```

It may be just a view state issue.

Comment: I just simplify the code. Originally, there are more customizations in this part and when I select the last item, the one on the right is also selected. I have added an observer and the number of selected items pass from 1 to 2 during the selection